# ZKTeco SDK Fingerprint Scanner with ZKFinger and standalonesdk

Tags: c#, zkteco, zkemkeeper

I need to test and implement if it will be potable to send email to management once a door has been unlocked via a SF200 SKTeco device. My Question is: Do i need a device or does the ZKFinger SDK run as a virtual device. I will appreciate any advice.

I have downloaded the

standalone+sdk-6.3.1.37-doc-2.1.0-demo-1.1.15. as well as the ZKFingerSDK 5.3_ZK10.0 SDK.

I also installed the ZKAccess3.5 .

It is unclear if i need a physical device or if the ZKFinger runs as a virtual fingerprint device.

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not ZKTeco support

Comment: Sorry for asking the question here. I do not know of any other platform for asking ZKTeco questions

Comment: can you pls give me the download link of ZKFingerSDK+5.3_ZK10.0.rar. I have one but showing damaged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a physical device.
ZKTeco doesn´t provide virtual devices to test their software.

Best regards.

Comment: Thank you. I have managed to get on to the network and are able to run the standalone+sdk-6.3.1.37-doc-2.1.0-demo-1.1.15. So at least im moving forward. How is your knowledge with the sdk's for ZKTeco. Under the tap OpLogMng it only logs that the door opened via the exit button how will i configure the op log to log when the door opens with a fingerprint aswell . Will i need the ZKTime SDK ?

Comment: Take a look at this post:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1104538/Csharp-ZKTeco-Biometric-Device-Getting-Started

Comment: Thank man. I am using the  standalone+sdk-6.3.1.37-doc-2.1.0-demo-1.1.15.and managed to send the emails directly from the active event log. But my next problem that i am facing is that i can not edit the GUI to add a additional tab.

Comment: OK... I´m really sorry that can´t help you with modifying the demo, that´s a totally different question from what was asked here... XD

Check that the tab control isn´t into a user control defined outside of the main window.